# How to prevent parse errors from stopping linux command execution chain

Tags: php, linux, bash, laravel, gitlab-ci

We have a CI server that automatically runs our tests.  Everything works great except this morning a build was pushed up that when "phpunit" ran it hit some bad php syntax which exited the below execution chain so that `artisan ci:cleanup` was never run.

```
php artisan ci:prepare
./vendor/bin/phpunit
php artisan ci:cleanup
```

The tail end of GitLab-CI's log output is below, showing that this parse error prevented the cleanup from running.

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in /home/gitlab_ci_runner/gitlab-runners/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-9/app/lib/Tests/Shared/Controllers/Api/AuthTest.php on line 64
```

I'd prefer to avoid writing a bash file or something to handle execution/errors, but I still need for the output to show in GitLab-CI's logs as it normally does.

How should I best approach handling this kind of terminating error where it doesn't prevent the cleanup from running?

Comment: What is preventing the next command from running if this command exits unsuccessfully? Is there something like a shell's `set -e`?

Answer (score 0):

One (fairly hacky) way of working around this is to add `|| true` to the end of the command. eg:

```
./vendor/php/phpunit || true
```

This should get around any error trapping in place.

Comment: I'd like for it to fail if there's a syntax error.  So `|| false` should do it?  That's interesting...

Comment: No, `|| false` will always fail.